# Docker Java Spring Boot RestFull MySql with Angular frontend

Tags: java, mysql, docker

I have 2 apps:

- A java Spring RestFull app with a MySql database
- Angular front end

Both app are running fine and i have them on Heroku. I needed to make changes to the Angular app in order to host on Heroku.
They use @CrossOrigin to communicate between each other.

I am now trying to host this stack on a VM, i use Digital Ocean and have set up a docker machine.

The ultimate goal is to use Kubernetes but i am still trying to get my head around Docker.

At the moment i think that Docker-compose generating the following:

- Java Spring Rest container app exposing a port
- MySql container exposing a port
- Angular conainer exposing a port
- nginx container exposing port 80. entry port for everything

is this the best approach?

- I think that there is a better way for the containers to communicate with each other.
- is it possible to test this stack locally before i try to host in the cloud.
- do all the containers need to be pushed to a repository like Docker hub which only allows one private repository before you can pull them down to use with digital ocean docker droplet.
- can the complete docker configuration be put in the one Private repository provided by docker hub